# Xcode 8.1 Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Hi there I am currently trying to get the following Scene to scale correctly for any scene. [image: iPhone 7 View]

This is currently how it looks on a iPhone 7 Plus:

[image: iPhone 7 Plus]

I managed to get it to scale the blue background correctly by adding the following constraints:
[image: Background Constraints]

However, I don't know how to get the UIImageView, UITextField and UI Label to scale in the same way. I Want them to keep the same proportions as they have now on the iPhone 7 view. I have looked for youtube tutorials but none seem to show how to introduce a way to have these items scale as I want them to.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting similar constraints on your other views?

Comment: Yes, I just did that but I think I might've solved it by setting the x/y positions for the label and following text box.

Comment: I hadn't been doing that and now it appears to be scaling correctly so I will test it on a device and check if it works....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add constraints between UIImageViews, Labels, the window, etc. by holding `control` and clicking-and-dragging between two elements. For example,

**UIImageView**: add these constraints:

- Vertical Spacing to Layout Guide (This constrains the top of the image to the top of the window)
- Leading Space to Container Margin (Left side of image stays 'connected' to the left side of the window)
- Trailing Space to Container Margin (Right side of image stays 'connected' to the right side of the window)
- Vertical Spacing (vertical spacing between the image and the Label)

You can use this same idea to constrain the Label and Text Field to the left side of the window and to keep the vertical spacing between the UIImageView, Label, and Text Field consistent on all devices.

Comment: Hi I have done as you said and it appears fine on the storyboard (on an iPad Pro) however, when I run it on a iPad 2 there is a black space all around the app.

Comment: Are the constraints on your blue-background correct? Does the black space surround this background element?

Comment: Have you set the app to 'Universal' (both iPhone and iPad) in the project settings?

Comment: Another idea, if the blue-background element is causing problems, it may be better to delete this element and set the "Background" attribute in the "Attributes Inspector" (found at the top of the panel on the right in Xcode)